# NoMethodError: undefined method `username' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

### Environment

- Ruby **[2.6.6]**
- Rails **[4.2.8]**
- Devise **[4.7.3]**

### Current behavior

Hello people,
I am facing issue while user is already signing and my apps perform actions successfully which are basically callbacks after login and routing to search page.
Basically I am using a before_action named as `:requires_auth_token` which has been used in my all controllers (i.e search,message,cart,etc).

And above before action method is been stored in my base_controller below here is the snippet for same.

```
def requires_auth_token
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      self.current_user_token = UserToken.find_by(
        token: token,
        installation_identifier: options[:installation_identifier]
      )
      self.installation_identifier = options[:installation_identifier]
      if session[:utoken].blank?
        user = self.current_user_token.try(:user)
        if user.present? && user.active?
          self.current_user = sign_in(:user, self.current_user_token.user)
          session[:utoken] = token
        end
      else
        if self.current_user_token
          if self.current_user_token.current_token_valid?(@org)
            self.current_user = self.current_user_token.user
          else
            sign_out(:user)
            self.current_user_token.destroy
            session[:utoken] = nil
          end
        end
      end
      set_user_context
      self.current_user.present? ? self.current_user : false
    end
  end
```

So here my code breaks out at `:set_user_context` beacause I am using HoneyBadger(Application for trace out the error if any ) for checking the errors in my app while its production.

Below is the code for `:set_user_context`:

```
def set_user_context
    Honeybadger.context(
      username: current_user.username,
      user_email: current_user.email, 
      user_id: current_user.id, 
    )  if current_user
  end
```

So this gives me error as **`NoMethodError: undefined method username for true:TrueClass`**

For which it seems to me this is because of this line :-
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/400eaf7fbe05f50b48c08dc7dbf23259cbdb8bdb/lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb#L51

As it returns boolean `true` value and stored in `self.current_user`.
Can some one here explain me why this is behaving differently is this issue with warden ?

### Expected behavior

### Here expected behaviour is the return user active-record object instead of true value.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: did you check what sign in methods is returning to you.
only following lines sets current user so I think it is sigh in method

self.current_user = sign_in(:user, self.current_user_token.user)
self.current_user = self.current_user_token.user

Comment: @shoaibsabir Its returning true for some api calls. I have added puts to check on each line and checked that its returning true after **self.current_user = sign_in(:user, self.current_user_token.user)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the answer provided by @jeffdill2 and your understanding.
Yes, the method `sign_in(:user, self.current_user_token.user)` returns `true` and you are assigning it to `self.current_user` due to which any methods you are expecting to use on the user object would not work.

You can update the logic as below and check if it helps:

```
      if session[:utoken].blank?
        user = self.current_user_token.try(:user)
        if user.present? && user.active? && sign_in(:user, user)
          self.current_user = user
          session[:utoken] = token
        end
      else
        # [...More logic]
      end
```

Comment: I will try your code and get an update on this as this is replicating on production. But same question to you @KunalK why is this returning boolean true value this?

Comment: This has some what fix my HB for now so marking this answer but the issue was due to *"#<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x7fdb6d0c36b8 not yet loaded>"*

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely here:

```
self.current_user = sign_in(:user, self.current_user_token.user)
```

The `sign_in` method returns a boolean, so you're setting `self.current_user` to a boolean (in your case `TrueClass`), instead of a `User` object (or whatever user class you're using).

Comment: You are correct @jeffdill2. but my question is why its returning true boolean value. Because in my staging env i have same functionally same api calls but it doesn't breakout there it doesnt return true value there. I know this is weird situation, Fixing set_user_context method is not my solution here i can remove that method then it will not return 500 error.

Comment: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/700284fc6741ed9c18654dc7538301bad923da2c/lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb#L33-L55

Comment: I already given that file with link and line number above in my post . @jeffdill2